# .getScript() equivalent in MooTools?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I was wondering if there is a MooTools equivalent to jQuery's `.getScript()`? I'm pretty certain that this exists somewhere in MooTools but I haven't been able to find it yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with MooTools, but it looks like you can use [`Asset.javascript`](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Utilities/Assets).

```
var myScript = Asset.javascript('/scripts/myScript.js', {
    id: 'myScript',
    onLoad: function(){
        alert('myScript.js is loaded!');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! Not exactly what I'm looking for, but this is a lot better than something else I saw online :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, isn't `Asset.javascript` basically identical to `jQuery.getScript`?

Comment: I'm so sorry... you're right! I was looking at your code snippet on my iPod Touch and I guess I didn't have my head on straight :D
So yes, like you said, `Asset.javascript` is basically the same thing as `jQuery.getScript` (except it seems more verbose, like the rest of MooTools). Thanks for pointing that out :)